# How to update Memcached content

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

Is it possible to update the memcached content?
(I am using PHP Memcached)

This is my current work flow:

1. First I retrieved the content through DB.
2. Second time, same request, it is from cache.
3. Whenever some action happens (i.e favourite the links), I flush the cache and get the results from DB.

Is it possible to get the updated content only from cache
(if one record deleted, remove the record from cache and display the cache content).

Comment: @vishnu - When there is update on database, you should repeat step 1 and step2 to ensure memcache is synchronized

Comment: @ajreal - Thanu for u r reply. you mean to say, it is not possible to update in cache content, later(run cron job script) insert in to database

Comment: @vishnu - It is possible to save changes to memcache first, then later update back to database. **BUT** data inside memcache will prune if memory size not enough. And if this happen, your changes will lost. What is your underlying intention?

Comment: @ajreal - Actually my web app is storing large number of browsed pages with the snapshots. The main intention is to increase the performance of web application instead of the querying each time to mysql DB (For tag,delete and favourite) - is there any way to deal with this type of traffic. can u suggest any different methods available to deal with this type of traffic. my website:http://www.hooeeywebprint.com

Comment: @vishnu - Cache warm up(background processing) could be useful. Also consider parallel fetching (instead of sequentially get single memcache at one call, you can combine multiple get in one call)

Answer (score 0):

never attempt to flush a memcache

instead have a single version value or such that is read before the page fetched from memcached this version is concatenated with the name of the page this way you can both prefill the cache by putting the new version before changing the version which is read by the deliverers this version can even be placed in the memcache as a value which would be only fetched from the database if it isn't present

this is basically a rough summary of [The Secret to Memcached](http://blog.leetsoft.com/2007/05/22/the-secret-to-memcached.html)

Comment: link forgot .html => http://blog.leetsoft.com/2007/05/22/the-secret-to-memcached.html